# Getting the inner html of multiple paragraph tags. When they are represented as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, algorithm

I need to get the inner HTML of multiple paragraph elements that are in a string.
Here's an example input:

```
var HTML = "<p class="Paragraph" >Hello, World 1!</p><p class="Paragraph" >Hello, World 2!</p>
```

Here's what I want the output to be:

```
var result = "Hello, World 1!Hello, World 2!"
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: a) parse the html b) get the `innerText`

Comment: Does the paragraph elements contains only text or are there other tags included like <p>Hallo <span>Max</span> nice to see you!</p> ? Or does this not disturb if they are in the result included?

Comment: @Sascha they can also contain div's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses a regular expression to match paragraph text as you describe in the question.

```
// A regular expression matching <*>*</*>.
const regex = /<[\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/[\s\S]*?>/gm;
const html = `<p class="Paragraph" >Hello, World 1!</p><p class="Paragraph" >Hello, World 2!</p>`;

let output = '';
let matches = regex.exec(html);
// Loop until there are no more matches.
while (matches) {
    // Regex produces an object where the matching text is stored at index 1. See: 
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
    // For more details.
    output += matches[1];
    // Look for another result.
    matches = regex.exec(html);
}

console.log(output);
```

Notes:

- In the regular expression, `[\s\S]` means match any character, including newlines.

Comment: this doesn't work for me because inside of the p tag I have things like ```class="Paragraph"```. Also when tried editing it to be this ```const regex = new RegExp("<p([\\s\\S]*?)>([\\s\\S]*?)</p>", "gm");``` the output was ```class="Pargraph"```

Comment: You were moving in the right direction, but do not need a capture group - signified by `(` and `)` - in your HTML tags. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Russoptomus Thanks that worked! But is there a way to make it work with more complex HTML like this  ```<p class="Pargraph">testing 2<div><br><p ="true" class="Pargraph DeleteAbleElement">testing 3</p></p>```

Comment: This is becoming a different question than what you originally asked for, and for that complexity I don't think I would use regular expressions, but probably an HTML parsing package.

Comment: @Russoptomus Thanks for all your help. I ended up using Parse5 to parse the HTML.

Comment: @maxall4 Great, would you consider accepting this answer?